# Loading soundpool in class extending fragment activity android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, soundpool

I am developing an android app. My class extends fragmentactivity.I am using soundpool,  using asyc to load the sounds to soundpool.
I am calling the async in the oncreate of the class, and I am playing the sounds inside onpagechagelistner. When I run the app, I am getting null pointer exception.

Please have a look the my onpagechangelistner and Async below.

```
_mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()  
    {
        public void onPageSelected(int page)  
        {
            if(page==0)
            {
                soundPool.play(1, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
            }
            else if(page==1)
            {
                soundPool.play(2, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
            }
            else if(page==2)
            {
                soundPool.play(3, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
            }
     }
protected class MainSoundsforalphabetsleftout extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean>
 {
    boolean result = false;
   @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        Log.e("inside","doin bg");
        soundPoolMapForAlphabetsleftout.put(1, soundPoolForAlphabetsleftout.load(AlphaPager.this, R.raw.tellme, 1));
        soundPoolMapForAlphabetsleftout.put(2, soundPoolForAlphabetsleftout.load(AlphaPager.this, R.raw.okay, 1));
        soundPoolForAlphabetsleftout.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) 
            {
                globe.setSoundPoolForalphabetsleftout(soundPoolForAlphabetsleftout);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( Boolean result ) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    Log.e("inside","postexecute of left out alpha");        
                    soundPoolleftout = globe.getSoundPoolForalphabetsleftout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
                Log.e("inside","preexecute of left out alpha");         
            }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
           }
```

Please help me out. Working on it since two days.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, show us the stacktrace; it will show at what line in your code exactly you're getting your null pointer and what it was doing before that.

Also, show where and how you're initialising that soundpool. Is it a singleton class or is it declared in the activity? I use the following

```
private static SoundManager _instance = null;
private SoundPool mSoundPool;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
private AudioManager  mAudioManager;
private Context mContext;
```

with the hashmap storing my sounds (and methods to play, pause, stop playing sounds).

Point is, show more code :) We can't see where things might be going wrong.
`